# Convolution to reduce popcorn noise in black and white video

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, video, pytorch

I have a black & white video as a tensor with the shape [Time, Width, Height] with [popcorn noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burst_noise) and I would like to reduce the noise by naively convolving along the time dimension.

Using a [Pytorch forum post as a starting point](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/1d-convolution-on-4d-input-tensor-to-reduce-the-temporal-dimension/98962/2?u=seanny123), I wrote the following function:

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

# dummy input tensor
input_tensor = torch.rand(100, 32, 32)

with torch.no_grad():
    t = input_tensor.view(1, *input_tensor.shape).transpose(1, 2)   # swap seq and channels dim -> SHAPE: [C, T, H, W]

    # define the low-pass filter kernel
    kernel_size = 5
    kernel = torch.ones(kernel_size) / kernel_size

    # convolve along the time dimension
    conv_temp = nn.Conv3d(1, 1, kernel_size=(kernel_size, 1, 1), bias=False)
    conv_temp.weight.data = kernel.view(1, 1, kernel_size, 1, 1)
    output_tensor = conv_temp(t).squeeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
```

Is this the right approach? Am I using the API correctly?

Comment: "_right approach_?" Does your code work correctly, do you see de-noised video results? I really do appreciate that you tried to offer a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But `torch.rand(100, 32, 32)` is just a TV tuned to a station that went off the air. Consider replacing it with a proper [telegraph process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegraph_process).

Comment: @J_H I do see denoised results on my confidential data I'm working with. I'll think about coming up with a reasonable minimal example.